# JQuery dialog-div (in WP admin area) with ' autoOpen' set to false just not working

Tags: jquery, dialog, show-hide

I have written a little Wordpress plugin which is meant for maintaining aBiz's Branches data. In the 'Admin' area under a custom new TopLevel menu and it's submenu (the code beneath is from that submenu's form. The plugin activates and creates the TopLevel menu and submenu just fine.)

But, my Div (popup)`(<div id="dialog-form")` shows immediately.

I am using `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` 
and if I use `jQuery('#dialog-form').hide();` in it , or alert on the obj var it is there and is fine.

The rest eg   `'autoOpen'  : false,` does nothing

```
<div class="wrap" id="main">
<form name="Sandwich Baron Branch Maintenance" method="post" action="<?php echo str_replace( '%   7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">

<style>    
 body { font-size: 62.5%; }     
 label, input { display:block; }    
 input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }     
 fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }     
 h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }     
 div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }     
 div#users-contain table 
{ margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }    
    div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th 
{ border: 1px solid #eee;  padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }     
.ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }     
.validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; } 

</style>

<?php 
add_action('admin_init', 'register_jquery_ui');
function register_jquery_ui() {
//apparently all that is required is the dependancy 'jquery-ui-dialog' (wp auto includes all this in the admin section, ...but whether that or this I have the same problem)
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog');
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min' );
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-bgiframe-2.1.2' );
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-mouse' );
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-button' );
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-draggable' );
 wp_enqueue_script( ‘jquery-ui-droppable’);
 wp_enqueue_script( ‘jquery-form’ );
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-position' );
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-resizable' );
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-effects-core' );
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-widget' ); 
 wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'); 
 // or A style available in WP 
 // wp_enqueue_style ('wp-jquery-ui-dialog');      

// admin_enqueue_script (  'my-modals-handle' ,'What bloody URL?' , array('jquery-ui-dialog')); // dependencies     

}
?>

<script>  
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
// jQuery('#dialog-form').hide();      //this works

var $info = jQuery("#dialog-form");   
// alert("$info = " + $info);           //this also works, shows we have the object, but the beneath does not.

//The rest is not working,...my div/dialog is visible immediately and not as a popup.(autoOpen is set to false....????)
 $info.dialog({ 
         'dialogClass'   : 'wp-dialog',
         'modal'         : true,
         'autoOpen'      : false,
         'closeOnEscape' : true,
         'buttons'       : {
         "Close": function() {
             jQuery(this).dialog('close');
         }
    }
 });
  $("#open-modal").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $info.dialog('open');
  }); 
}); 

</script>

<div id="dialog-form" title="Branch Editing" style="background-color:yellow;border:1px solid black;width:200px;height:200px;">
<p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
<form>
   <fieldset>
    <label for="BrName">Branch Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtBrname" id="txtBrName" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="Tel">Tel</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtTel" id="txtTel" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
   </fieldset>
</form>
</div>



<div id="dialog-form" title="Branch Editing">
<p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

<form>
<fieldset>
    <label for="BrName">Branch Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtBrname" id="txtBrName" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="Tel">Tel</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtTel" id="txtTel" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />


</fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
<?php             
    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='0' width='100%'>"; 
    echo "<tr> 
    <th>ID</th> 
    <th>Branch Name</th> 
    <th>Tel</th>
    <th>delete</th>
  </tr>"; 

global $wpdb;
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_sbbranches");

    // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table      
foreach ($myrows as $row) {               
            echo "<tr>"; 
            echo '<td style="border:none;">' .$row->BrId. '</td>'; 
            echo '<td style="border:none;">' .$row->BrName. '</td>'; 
            echo '<td style="border:none;">' .$row->BrTel. '</td>';

     echo '<td style="border:none;"><button onclick="create-branch(' . $row->Id. ')"></td>';
            echo '<td style="border:none;"><button onclick="fn_DeleteBranch(' . $row->Id. ')"></td>'; 

            echo "</tr>";  
    }  
    // close table> 
    echo "</table>";
?> 
<button id="create-branch(' 0 ')" >Create new branch</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Too many code lines, man. You only need one line or two to debug a css+javascript problem, don't make it too complex.

Comment: Had to,..some people find it helps.   The problem is def somewhere in this   $info.dialog({ 
             'dialogClass'   : 'wp-dialog', etc

Answer (score 0):

```
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog');
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min' );
```

Don't you think this is too much? I'm pretty sure that `jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min` already contains `jquery-ui-dialog` and other parts of library.

Comment: wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog');   is actually all that is needed inside the admin side... well apparently,..and does seem to work

Comment: but after some playing Rnd etc (swearing) I have a transparentish yellow dialog up. BUT the rest does not work                       var $info = jQuery("#dialog-form");  
     $info.dialog({ 
             'dialogClass'   : 'wp-dialog',
             'modal'         : false,
             'autoOpen'      : false,
             'closeOnEscape' : true,
             'buttons'       : {"Close": function() {
                 $(this).dialog('close');
             }
       }
   });